# Tumblr integration on ios

Tags: iphone, ipad, oauth, tumblr

I want to share my photo on **tumblr** as like we share on facebook or Twitter.
For that I used reference as http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2 and OAuth.

My problem is Using **OAuth** (as per developer blog tumblr is similar to twitter and so I just replace all key and api in code) I can **successfully login in tumblr in webview**,[image] and after click on Allow button (see in snap) I want authentication token but in my case I redirect on Callback Url which I passed when register my application.

And on done button clicked on webview I'm not got pin and that's why I can't get my token and receive `failedAuthorization` message.

Please suggest me any reference if possible or another way to post photo on tumblr.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you solve your problem, @Harin?

Comment: No still not, Actual my App requirement has been changed.But if you have any idea or if you get any solution please guide me.

Comment: Hm, I don't understand, why "Deny" or "Allow" buttons don't work still :( I press them and catch redirect url, take params like "oauth_token" and "oauth_verifier" and after that put them in header and go to /access_token. But... I can't understand, why after all operations I go next time at that webview and see the same "Allow"/"Deny" window :\\\

Comment: @Harin: did you solve the problem? I am facing the same issue. Please to post if you find the solution. ShareKit is not working with tumblr...i tried a few times.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not try with Share kit. It is most reliable source for sharing like:

Facebook,Twitter,LinkedIn,Tumbler. Try to implement with Share kit. It is easy to be

implemented also.

Comment: If possible then can you give me Github or tutorial url?

Comment: Try to implement with this links: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/sharekit/

Comment: I don't think so because these all social media sharing is only possible with share kit & it is easy to implement also. I never implement tumbler but I am very much sure that tumbler is easily be implemented via share kit...