# Image sharing via Tumblr and Path

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, path, tumblr

I am building one iPhone application in which I want to integrate 'Tumblr' and ' Path' api to share an Image.

By searching on stack overflow I found sharekit to share via 'Tumblr' and also found this [Tumblr integration on ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017986/tumblr-integration-on-ios) but it also says that this api is no more available.

I want to know that is it possible to share image via 'Tumblr' and 'Path'? if yes than please suggest me some way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: hello, any one knows how to achieve this ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794798/share-a-link-on-tumbler-from-ios-app