# Share a link on Tumblr from iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, tumblr

I've been googling around to find a way to share a link in tumbler... I just found sharekit to do this, and I really don't like it... What other options do you think I have for this?

I can't believe there are no libraries to achieve this in a relatively easy way...

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found this!

[TMTumblrSDK](https://github.com/tumblr/TMTumblrSDK)

It works fine! To make a text post you just have to:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    @"Titulo",@"title",
                                    @"Este es el body",@"body",nil];

[[TMAPIClient sharedInstance] post:@"blogName" type:@"text" parameters:parameters callback:^(id var, NSError *error){
     NSLog(@"Error %@",error);        
}];
```

I hope it helps someone!

Comment: For some reason, since the TMTumberSDK has a dependancy on JXHTTP, I am experiencing problems with JXHTTP, causing memory problems and even crashes when sending a post request with the TMAPIClient.  Has anyone experienced these problems?

Comment: not really. It worked fine out of the box. Sorry I can't help.

Comment: Aw.. one more question, the project you used it on, were you using ARC?

Comment: Where could I get the blog name?

Comment: Hey @Andres would you please me tumbler integration

Comment: hey @Andres Is to able to Post without leaving the app?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind them leaving the app, you can create a URL of the format:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tumblr.com/share?s=&v=3&t=[Title]&u=[URL]"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

which will open a tumblr window in Safari with the [Title] and [URL] fields pre-populated.  Or,

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tumblr://text?title=[Title]&link?url=[URL]"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Which will do the same, but with the tumblr iOS app, if the user has it installed.  If you want to stay in-app, you could make WebView which contains option #1.

Comment: Thanks, those are great solutions, but I need to post in background when the user clicks a button... something like twitter, if the user accept the app to access twitter I tweet in background...

Comment: In that case (your application is posting as the user), you'd have to use Tumblr's API (http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) and get authorization to post with the users' credentials using OAuth (http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#auth).  I can't be very much help there, but maybe you can figure it out with tumblr's documentation.